# entity framework lazy loading problen

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am facing a problem. After running a select statement I make lazy loading false. In that case, reference objects are null. But when debug my code everything works fine.referencr are loaded correctly. if I put waiting time before bl.LazyLoading(false) then it also works. Is there any way to detect reference are loaded? I have to wait until reference loaded. Is their any better Idea?I am not interested to use include() or reference() method.

```
using (var bl = new BusinessLayer<T>())
{
    bl.LazyLoading(true);
    var list = bl.GetAll();
    //wait
    bl.LazyLoading(false);
    if (list.Any())
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, list, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    }
    else
    {
        _logger.WriteInfo(String.Format("{0} list is empty.", key));
        throw new Exception(String.Format("{0} list is empty.", typeof(T).Name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your `bl.LazyLoading` method.

Comment: _context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = enable;

Comment: If `GetAll` is an asynchronous method, it should really return an asychronous wrapper (such as `Task<List<T>>`) that can synchronize the data once the caller requires it.

Comment: Have you tried to run the query like `GetAll.ToList()` before setting `LazyLoading` false?

Comment: Yes between true and false.@selva

Comment: it's not the asynchronous method but it behaves like asynchronous.@IllusiveBrian

Comment: So you want to temporarily disable lazy loading, and ensure all references have been lazily loaded before you're enabling lazy loading again? Then why not simply use eager loading instead (i.e. why not use the `Include()` method)?

Comment: I am not sure which table has to be loaded. pass just generic T, the table will be loaded accordingly.@bassfader

Comment: The real problem here is that you're at risk of running multiple operations on one context instance. As said above, if `GetAll` is an asynchronous method it should return a `Task<T>`. The easiest way to handle this is to make it an `async` method (as in, the keyword `async`) and  `await` it. By the way, why do you need lazy loading in the `GetAll` method? your question is not clear because you don't show the most relevant pieces of code.

Answer (score -1):

Entity Framework has 4 different method for implementing lazy loading mechanism:

1. Use include method;
2. Virtual collection into entity class;
3. Select() method;
4. Entry() and Load() methods;

Approaches 3 and 4 will still load possible related entities;

More detailed you could read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: You're mixing up explicit loading, eager loading, and lazy loading. But apart from that, how does this answer the question? ("Is there any way to detect reference are loaded?")